# Error while opening files in Java

Tags: java

I have developed a system using Java. I can save pdf, doc files etc. and they are saved in `jTable`. I want to open these files by clicking `Jtable` row. If I try to open saved files in my local disks, they won't open. But I can open files on removable disk. Please help me to solve this problem.

Here is my code:

```
 int row = jTable1.getSelectedRow();


        try {
        String value = (jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(row, 2).toString());

            //  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler" + value);
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + value);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

Open file and get directory path:

```
try {

    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();

    chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
    chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    File selectedPfile = chooser.getSelectedFile();
    jTextField1.setText(selectedPfile.getAbsolutePath());


} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Save code:

```
try {

            Connection con = DB.connect();

            PreparedStatement p = con.prepareStatement("insert into documents values( '" + jTextField3.getText() + "','" + jTextField2.getText() + "', '" + jTextField1.getText() + "')");

            p.executeUpdate();
            p.close();

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "save success");


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

Path saved in DB
[image]

Comment: "_If I want to open saved files in my local disks it wont be open_" What is the exact exception/behavior you get?

Comment: Do the paths get set correctly in the table? What happens when you try to run it?

Comment: If I save the file which located in pen drives, I can open this file when I clicked but same as I save file from my local disks c or d , I won't be open, nothing happen. Above picture shows how the path has been saving.

Comment: You're using the prepared statement wrong. You must use parameter marker placeholders and set their values. You are losing the backslashes from your paths by interpolating the values directly into the SQL statement. The reason it works on a removable disk is the files are in the root directory and need no backslashes in their paths.

Comment: Thanks Mr.David Conrad. It worked well. I am very appreciated for your promptly response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backslashes are lost from the paths when saved to the database because the strings are interpolated directly into the `PreparedStatement`, instead of being set as parameters. Do this instead:

```
try (Connection con = DB.connect()) {
    try (PreparedStatement p = con.prepareStatement(
            "insert into documents values (?, ?, ?)")) {
        p.setString(1, jTextField3.getText());
        p.setString(2, jTextField2.getText());
        p.setString(3, jTextField1.getText());
        p.executeUpdate();
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    // handle exception...
}
```